# Show Image when click array of JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

I wrote two way to show Image when cliked an array of JPanel, but it doesn't show Image.

This is my code:

```
public class Mutil_Image_2 implements MouseListener {   

    public JPanel [][]sub=new JPanel[10][10];
    public JPanel screen = new JPanel();

    public JFrame f = new JFrame("Draw on Panel");
    public static int v1,v2; 
    public static int x1 =1,y1=1;

    public Mutil_Image_2(String title)
    {

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //Full Screen

        screen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        screen.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));    

        int dem =0;
        for (int i=0; i<=9;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=9;j++)
            {                   
                sub[i][j]= new JPanel();
                sub[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));             
                screen.add(sub[i][j]);

                v1=i;
                v2=j;               
                sub[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
                f.add(screen);
            }

        }
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Mutil_Image_2("Grid Layout");    
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }   
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {       
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JPanel source = (JPanel) e.getSource();     
        BufferedImage img1;

        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)    
        {                       
            x1=e.getX();
            y1=e.getY();
            //source.setBackground(Color.black);
            source.setSize(500, 500);

            try { // The first way to show Image
                img1 =  ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Pict3.png"));
                JLabel picLabel = new JLabel (new ImageIcon(img1));
                source.add(picLabel);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   

            source.add(new draw_Image_in_MultiPanel()); //Second way to show Image          
        }   
    }
}

class draw_Image_in_MultiPanel extends JPanel {

    Image img1,img2;

    public draw_Image_in_MultiPanel() {         
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));   
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    }  

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int vt1 = Mutil_Image_2.x1;
        int vt2 = Mutil_Image_2.y1;

        try 
        {   
                img1 =  ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Pict3.jpg"));                    
                g.drawImage(img1, vt1, vt2, img1.getWidth(this),img1.getHeight(this) , Color.darkGray, this);
                g.drawString("Postion is:" + vt1 + " -" + vt2, vt1,vt2);


        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your first way:

```
    source.add(picLabel);
    //Followed by
    source.revalidate();
```

For your second way:

```
    source.add(new draw_Image_in_MultiPanel());
    //Again followed by
    source.revalidate();
```

Generally speaking, when you add or change a component after setting your JFrame to visible you should call "revalidate()" on the container. This tells Java to update the UI layout. I'm fairly certain this is your problem.

***EDIT***

After playing around with your code it seems to me that resizing and editing JPanels is going to cause you a lot of headache. Instead I have come up with an example that uses a JDialog to show the image when you click on a panel.
The JDialog acts as a panel that you can draw anywhere and it will always be above your other panels. This also means that all your panels can stay the same size. It also simplifies closing the panel when the user clicks somewhere else.
All your code is the same (minus the inner class that I deleted) any edits or deletions I made to your code were commented out so you can see what I changed and why.

```
public class Mutil_Image_2 implements MouseListener {


//A JDialog to show your image
public JDialog popup;
//A JPanel to store the last panel that was clicked.
public JPanel lastPane;

public JPanel[][] sub = new JPanel[10][10];
public JPanel screen = new JPanel();

public JFrame f = new JFrame("Draw on Panel");
public static int v1, v2;
public static int x1 = 1, y1 = 1;

public Mutil_Image_2(String title) {
    //Popup that is owned by your JFrame f.
    popup = new JDialog(f);
    //Initial location
    popup.setLocation(0, 0);
    //Initial size same as source in your original code.
    popup.setSize(500, 500);
    //Removes the window controls from the popup to make it look like a JPanel
    //Setting this to false will make the popup look like a JFrame.
    popup.setUndecorated(true);


    //Your original code for drawing all the JPanels
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Full Screen

    screen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    screen.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

    int dem = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            sub[i][j] = new JPanel();
            sub[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
            screen.add(sub[i][j]);

            v1 = i;
            v2 = j;
            sub[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
            f.add(screen);
        }

    }
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Mutil_Image_2("Grid Layout");
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JPanel source = (JPanel) e.getSource();
    BufferedImage img1;



    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {

        //Close the popup if the same panel was clicked twice
        if(lastPane != null){
            if(lastPane.equals(source)){
                popup.setVisible(false);
                lastPane = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        //If the above test was false we are clicking a different panel
        //assign this panel to lastPane so we can close the popup if
        //this pane is clicked again
        lastPane = source;

        //We now get the position of the click in the frames coordinates
        //Using e.getX/Y will return the click in panel coordinates, we don't want
        //that as we are positioning the popup relative to the JFrame.
        x1 = f.getMousePosition().x;
        y1 = f.getMousePosition().y;

        //Position the popup on the mouse click
        popup.setLocation(x1, y1);

        //Old code
        //x1 = e.getX();
        //y1 = e.getY();
        // source.setBackground(Color.black);
        //source.setSize(500, 500);

        try { // The first way to show Image
            img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Pict3.png"));
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));

            //Remove any components in the popups content pane
            //this essemntially gives up a fresh panel inside
            //the popup.
            popup.getContentPane().removeAll();
            //add picture to popup
            popup.add(picLabel);
            //show popup
            popup.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Give that a try, I believe it is what you are looking for and the simplest way I can think to do it.

In response to your other question about positioning the image:
You can either use a layout manager on popup's content pane or set the layout manager of the popup to null and use set position on your JLabel.

If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Many thanks from me to you. I tried and it works on the first way but in the second way java say:

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's interesting, I can't seem to replicate that error.

Comment: Do you need to perform both the first way and the second way or do you want the second way to only be performed if the first way fails. If it's the latter try pasting your second .add call in the catch block. It is a little redundant to use both methods if they both are intended to do the same thing.

Comment: How to clear another images when you click another Jpanel ? and how to set image in a (x1,y1) position when Jpanel show picture ?

Comment: Please see my last edit, I believe it will solve a lot of your problems.